# Target encoding using nested CV in sklearn pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am doing target encoding for my column, using nested cross validation approach (to avoid leakage) as mentioned [here](https://www.kaggle.com/c/mercedes-benz-greener-manufacturing/discussion/36136#201638), [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/11024/encoding-categorical-variables-using-likelihood-estimation) and [here](https://www.kaggle.com/code/tnarik/likelihood-encoding-of-categorical-features/notebook).

If I had to include my target encoding (by a custom transformer), in the sklearn pipeline, I need different transform function from the train set and the test set. This is because, for the train folds, the encoding is calculated using a further kfold split of the train data. Whereas for the test fold, encoding is mean of the train.

I know the sklearn pipeline will apply the same transformation for train and test split in the cv, is there a way to apply separate transformations for train and test splits using a sklearn pipeline and custom transformer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `category_encoders` package implements some target encoders. It gets around the issue of different training and testing dataset behavior by implementing a `fit_transform` method that is *not* equivalent to just `fit` followed by `transform`: `fit_transform` performs the training-set transformation, while `transform` performs the test/production set transformation.

Comment: Thank you. Can I use a custom transformer ?  instead of the ones available in the category_Encoders package ? The ones available in category_encoders would do nested split for target encoding that prevents leakage(atleast to my knowledge).
Is there a way with custom transformer where I can apply different logic with fit transform and transform ?

Comment: Sure, just take the same approach, defining `fit_transform` to perform the training-set transformation and `transform` to perform the test-set transformation.  However, their `TargetEncoder` doesn't perform any nested split; they have the `NestedCVWrapper` to wrap around other encoders if you want the nesting performed.

Comment: Thank you, will do. The custom Transformer , will automatically provide the fit_Transform method, if I subclass from the TransformerMixin class. Should I be not subclassing from the TransformerMixin, when I define my own fit_transform ?

Comment: Exactly, _don't_ use the inherited `TransformerMixin.fit_transform`, because that really is just shorthand for `fit` then `transform`.

Comment: Thank you @BenReiniger . I assume not subclassing TransformerMixin (for my custom transformer) will not create any other issues in the  pipeline right  (when I define my own fit_transform)? I was wondering if this class is useful for anything else I am not aware of, other than just the automatic fit_transform. All articles I see online say TransformerMixin is subclassed only to get the fit_transform automatically but don't provide any info on what else it is useful for.

Comment: @tjt The mixin doesn't currently do anything else, see [source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/36958fb240fbe435673a9e3c52e769f01f36bec0/sklearn/base.py#L836).