# Transformations , Hyper parameter tuning or Grid search, without a sklearn pipeline

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, grid-search

Because I need to do different transformations for train and test ([for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73438855/target-encoding-using-nested-cv-in-sklearn-pipeline) target encoding), I cannot use sklearn pipeline. Given this, what are options to efficiently (Simpler code and accuracy) apply the column transformations (for train and test cv folds separately) and also do hyper parameter tuning in sklearn /python.

I know I Cannot use grid search cv for tuning, since I cannot use pipelie. Should I be using the folds splits and do the transformations separately for train, test folds and repeat this for all combinations of hyper parameter tuning ?

Comment: "Because I need to do different transformations for train and test (for target encoding), I cannot use sklearn pipeline." This isn't exactly true. See e.g. the `category_encoders` package, which uses the different uses of `fit_transform` and `transform` to mark a distinction between training and testing sets.

Comment: Ah, just saw your other question, where that comment works as an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73439305/10495893